# MS-Execl: How to check not more than 1 cell contains more than zero?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have 3 cells:

D1 , D5 and D10 which contain values.

How do I show in D12 the word "Error" if more than 1 cell contains > 0.

For example:

D1 = 0, D5 = 0, D10 = 0  <---- OK

D1 = 1, D5 = 0, D10 = 0  <---- OK

D1 = 0, D5 = 5, D10 = 0  <---- OK

D1 = 0, D5 = 0, D10 = 9  <---- OK

D1 = 1, D5 = 5, D10 = 0  <---- Error

D1 = 1, D5 = 0, D10 = 9  <---- Error

D1 = 1, D5 = 5, D10 = 9  <---- Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the formula:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(D1,">0"),COUNTIF(D5,">0"),COUNTIF(D10,">0"))<2,"OK","ERROR")
```

It works in Excel 2010.  You may have to modify slightly to meet your needs (I wasn't sure it it should be >0 or <>0 because I didn't know if negative numbers were a concern or not), but that should get you going in the right direction and you can let me know if it doesn't quite give you what you need and we can try and tweak it to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: `=IF(COUNTIF(D1:D10,0)>1,"ERROR","OK")`

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your program

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=IF((D1=0)+(D5=0)+(D10=0)>1,"ERROR","OK")
```